# How to do this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to attach the method `copyToLeft` on `onClick` event of all images which are inside the `TD`. TD is inside the table named `mismatchList`, so that the structure becomes like this  `mismatchList > tbody > tr > td > img`

Although i have already done this, but that is using plain javascript. What i did was, i manually added `copyToLeft(this);` method on `onClick` event of all specified elements at the time of creation. [ This is the step which i want to omit and use jQuery to do this somehow ].

Also definition of `copyToLeft` goes like this:-

```
function copyToLeft(obj){
    leftObj = getLeftTD (obj);  // my method which returns the adjacent Left TD
    rightObj = getRightTD (obj);
    
    if ( leftObj.innerHTML != rightObj.innerHTML ) {            
        leftObj.innerHTML = rightObj.innerHTML;
        leftObj.bgColor = '#1DD50F';
    }else{
        alert ( 'Both values are same' );
    }
}
```

If required `copyToLeft` method's definition can also be changed. [ just in case you think, jQuery can be used to make this method better :) ]

---

## Edit

Instead of asking another question i am just adding the new requirement :)  [ let me know if i am supposed to create new one ]
i have to add `copyToLeft` method to all images as i specified, but alongwith that image src should be `left_arrow.gif`, and add `copyToRight` method if src is `right_arrow.gif`.  Also, how can we get the adjacent left/right TD in jQuery, as i want to replpace my `getLeftTD` and `getRightTD` method as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to match the image src.

```
$('#mismatchList > tbody > tr > td > img[src='left_arrow.gif']').click(copyToLeft);
$('#mismatchList > tbody > tr > td > img[src='right_arrow.gif']').click(copyToRight);
```

It is worth noting that the part matching the image src does use the entire contents of src, so if you move the images to a different directory it will stop working. If you just want to match the end of source you can use $= instead of just =.

Here's a variation on TheVillageIdiots rewrite of your copy left function.

```
function copyToLeft() {
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');
    var leftObj = cell.prev();
    var rightObj = cell.next();

    if ( leftObj.html() != rightObj.html()) {                        
        leftObj.html(rightObj.html());
        leftObj.css('background-color','#1DD50F');
    } else {
        alert ( 'Both values are same' );
    }
}
```

Part of me also thinks it would make sense to just have one copyToSibling function where you check $(this).attr('src') for whether it's left_arrow.gif or right_arrow.gif and act accordingly, rather than the two selectors I posted before.

Answer (score 4):

If i've understood your question correctly, in jQuery, you'd bind the event as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('mismatchList > tbody > tr > td > img').click(copyToLeft);
});
```

In your `copyToLeft` function, you don't accept `obj` as an input parameter, instead `this` will be the image. `$(this)` will be a jQuery object, containing the image, should you require it...

Comment: Very minor thing, but your selector would match an element called mismatchList. The question isn't clear on this, but I'm guessing it's either an id, in which case it should be #mismatchList or a class (.mismatchList).

Comment: well, yes, i just copied the selector straight away, as i didn't consider that to be a key part of the issue. if i'd optimize it, i'd say `#mismatchList img`, as there are not supposed to be any images in a table that are not contained in a `td` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td><img src="file:///...\delete.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td><img src="file:///...\ok.png" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table#tbl img").click(function(){
            var td=$(this).parents("td");
            var tr=$(td).parents("tr");
            var left=$(td).prev("td");

            $(left).html($(td).html());
        });
    });
</script>
```